# QT 5.5 - QNetworkReply empty data

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply

I already took at others questions but I didn't find an answer.
I have a problem to print HTML code I download with a `QNetworkAccessManager`.

I need to log into a website to retrieve this code.
I have a slot like this:

```
void Aims::slotRequestFinished(QNetworkReply* requestReply)
{
    QString data = QString(requestReply->readAll());
    qDebug() << data;
}
```

For the first two steps (connection), I can see the HTML code in the console.
The last step doesn't get any data. There is no redirection nor error.

Now, the stranger part is that when I change my code to show the page into a webview, `qDebug` doesn't show anything, but the code loaded is shown correctly in the webview.

```
void Aims::slotRequestFinished(QNetworkReply* requestReply)
{
    QString data = QString(requestReply->readAll());
    qDebug() << data;
    ui->webView->setHtml(data);
}
```

---

Well, I can save the content into a file. But I would really like to understand why I can't see anything in `qDebug`

Comment: You can get empty data if you call `requestReply->readAll()` multiple times on the same `QNetworkReply` object.

Comment: How do you handle errors?